# perl (Statistics::PCA): Can't use string ("0") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs"

Tags: perl, ref, strict

I'm trying to use the [Statistics::PCA](http://search.cpan.org/~dsth/Statistics-PCA-0.0.1/lib/Statistics/PCA.pm) package to conduct a PCA on some genetic variants. The package requires reading in a list of lists (if I understood it correctly, that can be an array of arrays, right?).

Below is part of my code where I create arrays for each individual (each individual is an actual human subject that gets an array filled with 0's and 1's, which represent the presence or absence of a genetic variant called an "SV"), and then push them in my array of arrays called @LoL_SVs:

```
my @LoL_SVs;

foreach (@individuals) {
    my $ind = $_;
    foreach (@all_SVs) {
        if ($SV{$ind}{$_} != 1) {
            push(@{$SVs{$ind}}, "0");
        }
        if ($SV{$ind}{$_} == 1) {
            push(@{$SVs{$ind}}, "1");
        }
    }
    push @LoL_SVs, [ @{$SVs{$ind}} ];
}
```

I then try to load the data as described on the [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~dsth/Statistics-PCA-0.0.1/lib/Statistics/PCA.pm) website of the module (see paragraph *load_data*):

```
use Statistics::PCA;

my $pca = Statistics::PCA->new;

$pca->load_data ( { format => 'table', data => @LoL_SVs, } ); 
# ^ this line is where it goes wrong
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, and I get the error message:

> Can't use string ("0") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /home/abdel/myperl/share/perl/5.10.1/Statistics/PCA.pm line 189.

Any idea what might go wrong here?

I hope the problem is well specified, otherwise please let me know if you need more info! Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your options in the `load_data` call include this:

```
data => @LoL_SVs
```

Whereas in the documentation it is described like this

```
data => [ \@Obs1, \@Obs2, \@Obs3, \@Obs4, \@Obs5 ],
```

You try to load an array, but the module expects an array ref (possibly of array refs). So when you try to pass an empty array as the scalar argument, it evaluates to `0` (because it contains 0 elements). Similar to:

```
my @bar;
my $foo = @bar;   # @bar is empty, $foo is 0
print $foo->[0];  # Can't use string ("0") as ARRAY ref ...
```

Your problem *may* be resolved by passing the reference to `@LoL_SVs`:

```
data => \@LoL_SVs
```

As a side note, it is good that you are using

```
use strict;
```

And I also hope that you are using

```
use warnings;
```

Without `strict` and with variable names like `@LoL_SVs` it is very easy to make typos such as `@Lol_Svs` which leads to hard to detect bugs. Without using `warnings`, such bugs would be even harder to find.

Comment: Thanks!! using "data => \@LoL_SVs" did the trick! I love this website.